# Using UWP api in windows phone 8.1 app on windows 10 mobile

Tags: reflection, uwp

I would like to use the UWP clipboard api of windows 10 in my windows phone 8.1 winrt app.

I couldn't load the Winmd file by using Assembly.Load(string assemblyname) method.

Is there another way to use it. Please some one point me in the right way. I'm not very experienced in reflection.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to use functionality from the Windows 10 SDK in an app using the Windows 8.1 SDK.